# Insert many rows returning id and update that ids in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with PostgreSQL, My sql structure:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE users (
    id_user serial,
    user_name varchar,
    id_user_description int
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE user_description  (
    id_user_description serial,
    age int
);
```

`users` table has some users:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name)
SELECT column1
FROM (
    VALUES
    ('John'),
    ('Amanda')
) t;
```

I am trying to insert data to table `user_description` and I also need to update inserted row ids to table `users`. My query is this:

```
WITH inserted_user_description AS (
    INSERT INTO user_description (age)
    SELECT age
    FROM (
        SELECT users.id_user,
            t.column1 AS age,
            t.column2 AS user_name
        FROM (
            VALUES
            (21, 'John'),
            (28, 'Amanda')
        ) t
        INNER JOIN users ON users.user_name = t.column2
    ) tt
    RETURNING id_user_description, tt.id_user
)
UPDATE users SET id_user_description = t.id_user_description
FROM (
    SELECT id_user_description, id_user
    FROM inserted_user_description 
) t
WHERE users.id_user = t.id_user;
```

But I get error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tt"
>   LINE 15:         RETURNING id_user_description, tt.id_user

How could I fix this?

Comment: The error message does not match the posted code

Comment: What do you mean? Why not? Of course you should remove <...> where I removed more columns

Comment: put original sql and error if you want help

Comment: I added specific case and structure

Comment: "The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html
`tt.id_user` is not present in the inserted row.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a valid SQL snippet that illustrated how it works. You have 2 tables `a` and `b`. You want to update `b` when you insert rows in `a`.

`a` and `b` schema:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id serial unique,
    some_int int
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    id serial,
    a_id int,
    some_date timestamp
);
```

Let's insert some rows into `b` to match the ones we will insert in `a` (they are the rows we will update):

```
INSERT INTO b (a_id, some_date)
SELECT generate_series, null
FROM generate_series(1, 100);
```

Now, here is how to insert rows in `a` and update equivalent rows in `b`:

```
WITH inserted as (
    INSERT INTO a (some_int)
    SELECT *
    FROM generate_series(1, 10)
    RETURNING id
)
UPDATE b
SET some_date = NOW()
FROM inserted i
WHERE i.id = b.a_id
;
```

As you can see, 10 rows where inserted in `a` and the 10 equivalent rows where updated in `b`:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM a;
 id | some_int 
----+----------
  1 |        1
  2 |        2
  3 |        3
  4 |        4
  5 |        5
  6 |        6
  7 |        7
  8 |        8
  9 |        9
 10 |       10
(10 rows)

test=# SELECT * FROM b WHERE some_date IS NOT NULL;
 id | a_id |         some_date          
----+------+----------------------------
  1 |    1 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  2 |    2 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  3 |    3 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  4 |    4 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  5 |    5 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  6 |    6 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  7 |    7 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  8 |    8 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
  9 |    9 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
 10 |   10 | 2017-03-16 17:48:32.257217
(10 rows)
```

**Update:**

In your specific case, this is what I believe your query should look like (always hard to write queries without the schema!):

```
WITH inserted_user_description AS (
    INSERT INTO user_description (age, <...>)
    SELECT u.id_user,
        t.column1 AS age,
        <...>
        t.column8 AS user_name
    FROM (
        VALUES
        (21, <...> ,'John'),
        (28, <...> ,'Amanda'),
        <...>
    ) t
    JOIN users u ON u.user_name = t.user_name
    RETURNING id_user_description, u.id_user
)
UPDATE users
SET id_user_description = t.id_user_description
FROM inserted_user_description t
WHERE users.id_user = t.id_user;
```

Comment: Your first example is different from my case, b.id and b.a_id in my case can be different.

Comment: As for the update. I have error: INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Comment: I have updated the question with specific case with schema